# C# Double values not printing

Tags: c#

Okay so my program is supposed to take values that the user gives and then performs a calculation with them and then returns them, the problem is that when I try to write a Console.WriteLine to print the values, nothing appears where the variable should and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

```
        double HumanStrideLength = 0;
        double HumanHeight;
        double HumanVelocity;
        double HumanStrideFrequency = 0;
        string Answer;
        string AnimalName;
        double AnimalLength;
        double AnimalStrideLength;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome to Animal Run");
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Do you know your stride length?");
        Answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if ((Answer == "Yes") || (Answer == "yes") || (Answer == "y") || (Answer == "Y") || (Answer == "Yeah") || (Answer == "yeah"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input your stride length in CM");
            try
            {
                HumanStrideLength = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch(FormatException f)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your height in CM");
            HumanHeight = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            HumanStrideLength = HumanHeight * 0.413;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("test", HumanStrideLength);
```

So here where it is supposed to print the variable HumanStrideLength it instead prints just the word "test".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `Console.WriteLine()` with multiple arguments, the first argument must be a *format string*. This means that it has to contain something like `{0}`, which is a placeholder that will be replaced by the additional arguments to `Console.WriteLine()`. For example, change:

> ```
> Console.WriteLine("test", HumanStrideLength);
> ```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("test {0}", HumanStrideLength);
```

And the output you should see if `HumanStrideLength` is `12.3`, for example, will be:

```
test 12.3
```

or

```
test 12.3000001
```

due to floating point inaccuracy.

You can include multiple placeholders like this, with the number inside of each one corresponding to the zero-based index of the parameter that it will be replaced with:

```
Console.WriteLine("testing {0}, {1}", 2.3, 4.5);
```

will write "testing 2.3, 4.5" to the console. See [documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for more information on this.

If you want to be more concise, you can also just use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) instead of a format string. This feature was introduced in C# 6:

```
Console.WriteLine($"test {HumanStrideLength}");
```

Comment: Another way to do this is to do an inline `ToString` on the `WriteLine` for the variable.  This breaks common conventions used by many people in C#, but does in fact work...

Comment: @user2366842 `Console.WriteLine()` automatically calls `.ToString()` on variables passed as arguments.   I am not sure I follow your comment

Comment: My comment being you could go like such: `Console.WriteLine("testing " & HumanStrideLength.ToString());` or so.  You don't need to pass them through as arguments.

Comment: @user2366842 The concatenation operator in C# is `+`, not `&`.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm honestly a little rusty on my C#, as I spend the majority of my time in VB these days.